# How to manage multiple views in a single page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, model-view-controller, view, single-page-application

I am developing a single page application and trying to grasp MVC, MV* structure with vanilla JavaScript. At the moment I have a page that includes a lot of functionality and events. There are some parts of the page that needs to be dynamically rendered separately. Those parts have to interact with each other and a single Model. Creating a single View class for this page seems like it would make it very heavy.

[image]

My question is how do I best handle this kind of structure so that the code would be clean, clear and easy to test? Should I create a View for each Part in a page? Should I have those page parts interacting with each other or should they interact through a single controller, presenter? Or should they be working through the single View as some sort of partials?

Please provide some code examples in JavaScript if possible. Thank you..

Comment: You need a big model with all your data and use getters and setters to broadcast changes on the model. The view listens to the model change and __redraws either the whole or part of itself__ depending on what has changed. The view should never modify the model so you need to create a separate controller which job will be to modify the model after a view event. For instance when you init your app, you draw the whole view, when your user clicks on part 3(a list for instance),only the detail(part 1) is updated because only the current article value in the model has changed (use custom events)

Comment: That's a great answer. So you would have a single View that would redraw those parts. There would be a single controller to notify the Model. And then those Parts of the View would update according to the Model changes through the custom events.